# Ruby ActiveRecord has_many not running Join

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have a simple one-to-many relationship in my Ruby on Rails project I am using  2.6.6
And rails 6.0.3

```
Ruby V => 2.6.6
Rails V => 6.0.3

class Resource < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :project, :class_name => 'Project', :foreign_key => 'project_id'
  end

class Project < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :resources, class_name: 'Resource'

end
```

However when I run

```
Projects.all
```

the SQL generated does not perform the Join so I have no resources for any project. There is data in the database and the foreign keys are set correctly

```
irb(main):001:0> Project.all
SQL (0.9ms)  USE [Portfolio]
Project Load (3.3ms)  EXEC sp_executesql N'SELECT [projects].* FROM [projects] ORDER BY [projects].[id] ASC OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT @0 ROWS ONLY', N'@0 int', @0 = 11  [["LIMIT", nil]]
```

I am pretty new to Ruby and can't figure out why this simple ORM function is not working.
I can get this to return child data using "join" but in so doing I have to group the results whereas in another test project  set from a tutorial this worked as expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Project.all` just selects all records from the `projects` table.

If you want to use the relationships you have to iterate through the records or select one. It will however not perform a join as you said you expect, rather it will run two separate SQL statements.

```
projects = Project.all
projects.each do |project|
  project.resources
end

# or something like
project = Project.find(1) #by id = 1
project.resources
```

[The Rails guides](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) on this are quite good to start with.

---

PS: You can skip the `:class_name => 'Project', :foreign_key => 'project_id'` part since they are all default values used by Rails. The same goes for `class_name: 'Resource'`

Comment: I see it is all to do with lazy loading. Just very different approach from what I'm used to in c#. Thank you very much for you answer

Comment: You can lazy load or eager load it with `Project.all.includes(:resources)`